# Efficient construction of cosine similarity matrix from corpus in Chapel

Tags: sparse-matrix, cosine-similarity, chapel

I have a corpus `V` of TF/IDF vectors, so they are pretty sparse.
It's an array about 2,500 by 150,000.
I want to calculate the cosine similarity between each document in the corpus.

This is almost the most naive way I can think of to do it.  I know of three or four optimizations already, but I don't want to assume the answer.  I'd like know the most computationally efficient way to use Chapel in this calculation.  The goal is to get `X` as a symmetric matrix with `diag(X) = 0`

```
use Norm,
    LinearAlgebra;

var ndocs = 2500,
    nftrs = 150000,
    docs = 1..ndocs,
    ftrs = 1..nftrs,
    V: [docs, ftrs] real,
    X: [docs, docs] real;

for i in docs {
  var n1 = norm(V[i,..]);
  for j in (i+1)..ndocs {
    var n2 = norm(V[j,..]);
    var c = dot(V[i,..], V[j,..]) / (n1*n2);
    X[i,j] = c;
    X[j,i] = c;
  }
}
```

Compiled using

```
chpl -I/usr/local/Cellar/openblas/0.2.20/include -L/usr/local/Cellar/openblas/0.2.20/lib -lblas cosim.chpl
```

== UPDATED ==

This could should actually compile and run. Original code had errors as suggested by @bradcray below

Comment: Given a mathematical task ( a function maximisation ), what is the criterial function & what is the metric? Missing an explicit statement about that. What is the quantitative measure of *(cit.)* "the **most computationally efficient way** ( to use Chapel in this calculation )"? Thanks Brian for adding such a clear and sound statement to allow such optimisation efforts not to run against moving sands.

Comment: @brian-dolan: There are a number of bugs in the code above that I tried to edit, but it was rejected saying that I needed to communicate the edits to you instead.  The problems are that ndocs and nftrs are declared as domains, but then used to declare an array (where ranges are needed) and as a bound in the inner for loop (where an integer is needed).  Here's my proposed fix:

use Norm, LinearAlgebra;

var ndocs = 2500,
    nftrs = 150000, 
    docs = 1..ndocs, 
    ftrs = 1..nftrs,
    V: [docs, ftrs] real,
    X: [docs, docs] real;

for i in docs {

Comment: @Brad Please don't feel rejected!  Okay, I'll take a look and probably ask for more help.  Ah, so long ago when I knew nothing about programming...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some improvements that can be made to the original implementation:

- Pre-compute and cache `dot(V[i, ..], V[i, ..])` for all `i` into an array to reduce repeated computations.
- Use `1..V.size` or `V.domain` instead of `1..V.shape[1]`

  - `V.shape` is computed from the domain sizes, rather than stored as a field.
- Exploit the *embarrassingly parallel* nature of this program, by computing `X` in parallel

For more details see the [GitHub issue](https://github.com/buddha314/numsuch/issues/16) that explores these changes and their impact on the timings.

Answer (score 1):

[Meta: This question has been weighing on me due to its being unanswered for so long.  I've personally shied away from it due to its use of the phrase "most computationally efficient."  In practice, its hard to guarantee that any solution meets that description given variations that may occur from one target machine or dataset to the next.  But since nobody else has stepped up, I'll make some comments in hopes that they might be of use.]

A few things that stand out for me in your code:

1) Unless I'm missing something, you are computing `norm(V[r, ..])` redundantly many, many times during the computation.  Asymptotically speaking, this suggests that you're doing quadratic work where only linear work is required.  I'd suggest computing the norm for each row once and storing it in an array to avoid this redundant computation:

```
var normVrow: [docs] real = [r in docs] norm(V[r,..]);
```

Then, within the inner loop, you can just refer to `normVrow[i]` or `normVrow[j]`.

2) Since this is Chapel and your loop seems to have no cross-loop dependencies, rather than using serial `for` loops, you should probably use a parallel `forall` loop for this computation.  There's a question about whether to:

(a) change your outer loop to a `forall` (which would result in a load imbalance since the overall iteration space is triangular),

(b) change both loops to `forall` loops (which would help the load imbalance problem by over-decomposing, but likely also increase overhead), or

(c) make the outer loop into a dynamically scheduled loop to address the load imbalance.

My instinct would be to do option c using Chapel's [dynamic](https://chapel-lang.org/docs/1.16/modules/standard/DynamicIters.html#DynamicIters.dynamic) iterator:

```
use DynamicIters;

forall i in dynamic(ndocs) {
  ...
}
```

3) A final thing to consider would be to avoid the triangular iteration space and just redundantly compute `X[i,j]` and `X[j,i]` even though they'll have the same value.  This may not make sense on a shared-memory run, but if you were computing on a distributed array `X`, you'd likely reduce communication since those matrix values will be stored by different processors.  In this approach, you could iterate with a single `forall` loop over `X.domain`, and the result would be well-load-balanced by default without the need for the dynamic iterator.

Comment: Oops, I had a cached copy of this question in my browser, and hadn't noticed that @bencray had already answered it a few weeks ago.  My bad.